# Is d3.mouse( mySVG[0][0]) really the right way to address the container?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reference

Writing a small prototype using D3js, I wrapped out the playground into an `Game` object:

```
var Game = function(){
    this.svg = d3.select( "body").append( "svg")
        .attr( "width",  500)
        .attr( "height", 500)
    ;

    _this = this;
    this.svg.on( 'click', function(){ _this.click()});
```

To capture mouse clicks on the SVG I want to use D3's methods:

```
Game.prototype.click = function(){
    var M = d3.mouse( this.svg[0][0]);
    console.log( "Clicked: "+M[0]+':'+M[1]);
}
```

I really doubt that `this.svg[0][0]`, that I came up to after experiments, is the intended way of passing the container object in this case.

**Question**: what's the *right* way of passing the container to `d3.mouse()` function in D3js, having a varialbe holding the element?

Comment: `var M = d3.mouse(this)` should work; check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770763/mouse-position-in-d3#16770859)

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes, `this` is `Game` in my example, and is `window` in the linked one. So, no go.

Answer (score 1):

**Upd**. figured out myself: [`selection.node()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#node) does the thing. i.e.:

```
var M = d3.mouse( this.svg.node());
```

Comment: To be clear, `this.svg[0][0]` is a perfectly acceptable way of accessing the DOM node from a single-element d3 selection, it just makes for rather obscure code.  For that reason I tend to prefer the more intuitive and readable `selection.node()`.