# Get coordinates of mouse click on svg using d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I want to get the coordinates of a mouse click on a rectangular shaped svg.  I'm trying to print the mouse click coordinates to the console.

I can use `pageX` and `pageY` to get the coordinates, but that is of the entire page. I just need the coordinates inside the svg.

I'm using `d3.v3.min.js`

So I tried:

```
$(document).mousedown(function () {
     console.log(d3.mouse(this));
});
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sourceEvent' of null

I also tried:

```
$(document).mousedown(function () {
     console.log(d3.mouse(document.getElementById("svg_id")));
});
```

I get the same error.

When I try with `d3.svg.mouse(this)`, I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

How can I get the click coordinates in the svg and why are these `d3.mouse()` functions not working?

Comment: Wondering if this may help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770763/mouse-position-in-d3

Comment: thanks, but trying those examples I am still getting the sourceEvent null error.

Comment: I don't know d3 well, but a quick look at the docs suggest that the parameter should be a container (like an svg or g element). I have no idea what 'shape' is, but you may want to check that. Otherwise maybe post up a fiddle.

Comment: can you post the code of the svg element creation. The rectangular shape you mention.

Answer (score 15):

The problem with your code is that you're using jQuery event handling instead of D3 event handling. You want something like the following:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.on("click", function() {
    console.log(d3.mouse(svg.node));
})
```

Comment: To clarify: the values used by `d3.mouse` are set by d3 when it intercepts an event and passes it to your event handler; so, you can only use `d3.event(containerElement)` in an event handler registered with the d3 `.on()` method.

Comment: After a lot of mucking around, I found that just `d3.mouse(this)` worked inside the `svg.on('click')` function.

Comment: ``` var coords = d3.pointer( event );```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe time for an update here? Using JSv7, I think this would be the equivalent snippet:

`svg.on("click", d => console.log([d.clientX, d.clientY]));`

Lately it seems d3JS has gone to directly using the ClientX and ClientY properties of the node in which the event occurred without any sort of "mouse" object/methods.