# How do I get the mouse coordinates using mousedown in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coordinates, onmousedown

I am trying to create a graph in D3 where you can draw a square to zoom in. Right now, I am trying to get the mousedown function to work. I need to be able to click anywhere in the graph and get the coordinates. This is what I have now:

```
svg.on("mousedown", mousedown)
function mousedown()
{
    console.log(event.clientX);
}
```

I know this is not correct, but I can't seem to find how I can access the mouse's coordinates.

Comment: fix the code first. function mousedown(event) { ... }. the function takes the event parameter.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770763/mouse-position-in-d3

Answer (score 2):

firstly, you need to set up the click event properly.

```
svg.on('mousedown', function() { console.log(d3.event); } );
```

in your case:

```
svg.on('mousedown', mousedown);

function mousedown() {
  console.log(d3.event.clientX);
  console.log(d3.event.clientY);
}
```